# Can I the looks of dragablz tabs when they are being dragged?

Tags: wpf, tabs, drag-and-drop

This is the [library](https://dragablz.net/) I am referring to.

Currently, they look like this:[image: dragablz tabs showing whole window while dragged]

This is problematic for me because, in my eyes, this makes placing tabs inside the tabpanel difficult, as it is covered by the second window's background.
I'd like to find a way to perhaps blur the background or show only the tab itself when being dragged.